# Android Studios: I am unable to connect to server when using the mobile data connection

Tags: android, android-permissions

My app seems to connect to server and work only when I am using the wifi connection. However when I use the mobile network (mobile data) connection it does not connect to server. Does anyone have any suggestions what I should do? My AndroidManifest.xml permissions look like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I've never seen a problem like this. What do you mean by "network connection"? What errors are you seeing in the log? Works vs no-works??

Comment: I mean the mobile network. Probably my question is confusing, I will edit it.

Comment: If you could post failure logs or just list the connection errors you're seeing (400, etc, etc) then we could all assist you more maybe.

Comment: Where is your server running? And where is your app running?